# Why is Earth 1/3 the age of the universe?

Tags: observational-astronomy, solar-system, earth, cosmology, age

The Earth is 4.6 billion years old
The universe is 13.8 billion years old.
3 times the age of the Earth
Are there other planets with ages that are close to say 1/4 1/5 etc the age of the universe? Why would this happen?

Comment: Would you expect the Earth to be older or younger than it actually is? And for what reasons would you expect that?

Answer (score 2):

The (approximate) 3:1 ratio is nearly entirely co-incidence.  The other planets formed at the same time as the Earth, and are therefore of the same age.

The Earth is quite accurately dated to 4.54 billion years and multiplying by three gives 13.62 billion,  quite a bit less than the age of the universe.

There are other planets around other stars, some formed early in the universe, some formed recently. There is no reason to expect simple ratios of ages between planets and the universe.

Comment: *The (approximate) 3:1 ratio is nearly entirely co-incidence.* Playing devil's advocate, is it? Perhaps older stars with older planets could not have developed intelligent life (which I'll define as life capable of escaping the planet's gravitational field and potentially communicate with life on other planets), and perhaps younger stars with younger planets have not yet had enough time to have enough time to have developed intelligent life. This is admittedly extrapolating from a sample size of one (the Earth), but for now, that sample size one one is all we have to go upon.

Comment: But nonetheless, plus one. Extrapolating from a sample size of one is a very bad idea.

Comment: What about 2 x 4.6 billion light years  for the anomalous galactic arc 3 billion light years long here at :https://www.sciencenews.org/article/galaxy-giant-arc-3-billion-light-years-long-cosmology-space

Comment: The formation of rocky planets would have been tricky for the first stars, since there was not much beyond hydrogen, helium, and a bit of lithium in the universe. Not quite sure when the formation of rocky planets would have become more likely than not...

Comment: @jon  yes, a close to 1:1 ratio is not possible, but there is no special reason to suppose that life on planets develops intelligence on a timescale that gives a fixed small ratio.  There is no resonance effect (for example) here.

Comment: @DavidHammen I see what you are saying, but I feel that this kind of anthropomorphic speculation is not particularly relevant.  It may be that intelligent life *tends* to develop at about a 3:1 ratio, but there is certainly no effect to lock the time that life develops intelligence at a small ratio, there is no resonance that causes this.

Comment: @JamesK - oh, for sure, playing random numbers game has no place here.

Comment: @DaveTheWave What about it?  "There is an object which has a light travel time that is about twice the age of the solar system". . .  But there are lots of things that are not a simple multiple of 4.6 billion, (and as noted, 4.6 is a rounded value)

Comment: The temperature of space was around the boiling point of helium 4.5 billion years ago when Earth formed.     https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/76241/cmbr-temperature-over-time                9 billion years ago (2 x 4.5) there was 3 times more hydrogen present as atomic gas as there was in stars ( hence the period of maximum star formation) .    https://phys.org/news/2021-06-gmrt-atomic-hydrogen-gas-mass.html    Could all be coincidence , I agree. But no harm in seeing what people think.

Comment: @DaveTheWave There is no such thing as "the" temperature of space. (What you link to is describing the temperature of the *cosmic background radiation*, not the temperature of gas in space.) The temperature of gas in space varies from a few degrees Kelvin to tens of millions of degrees, depending on the location.

Comment: @DaveTheWave The temperature of the protoplanetary disk from which the Earth formed varied with distance from the protostar that eventually would become the Sun. At about 1 AU (i.e., about where the Earth formed), the temperature probably was about 200 °C (for example, see https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0012821X18305697).

Answer (score 2):

The closeness to a 1/3 ratio is coincidence but the observation that the Earth is a lot younger than the universe may be quite profound.

Firstly, the Earth cannot be as old as the universe. The first galaxies and stars likely formed about 0.5-1 billion years after the big bang, once primordial hydrogen and helium had time to cool and clump.

Earth-like planets could not form around these stars, since there were no heavy elements like carbon, oxygen, silicon and iron present.

These elements are made inside stars and then dispersed into the interstellar medium for new generations of stars to incorporate that material. This process takes some time.

When the Earth formed, it was extremely hot, it was also being bombarded by asteroids and other sub-planetary bodies. There was no chance of forming life for 0.5 billion years or so.

Once life formed, it didn't have the capacity to estimate the age of the Earth and of the universe. That is a recent development and has apparently taken about 4 billion years of evolution.

If we assume that our galaxy took 1 billion years to form, that adequate chemical enrichment took another 2-3 billion years and that the time taken for a planet to cool and have evolved intelligent life is 4 billion years, then we arrive at the conclusion that the universe as we see it would have to be *at least* 7-8 billion years old and that our planet would then be less than about half the age of the universe.

A more interesting question is why is the 1/3 fraction quite close to, but still significantly smaller than, the apparent maximum of 1/2? We do know that small, rocky planets have formed around stars with a wide variety of ages - anything from a few million years to estimated ages of around 10 billion years (e.g. [Weiss et al. 2021](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.03071)), though how common they are around very old stars is still to be determined. Was the early galaxy inhospitable to life for some reason? Are we just part of a distribution, with many other older planets out there hosting more ancient life-forms?

Comment: Why the Earth isn't 1/2 age of universe is a good point I think it relates to the temperature of the cmbr being close to heliums boiling point at 1 atmosphere 4.5 billion years ago  There are exoplanets surrounded by helium .I wonder how old they are . Under oressure helium can be liquid  hotter than it is at 1 atmosphere Perhaps liquid  helium was trapped inside rocks before the planets and sun formed.

Comment: @DaveTheWave I'll be blunt: That is nonsense. You are thinking of helium as a superfluid, which only happens at extremely low temperatures. Those extremely low temperatures are not the temperatures at which planets form, whether they are terestrial planets, gas giants, ice giants, or even plutino dwarf planets.

Answer (score 0):

At least 40% of the field stars (thus outside globular clusters) seem to have planets, if not more.

Planets form around the protostar, thus at the same time as the stars. Assuming that the laws of physics are universal, then the distribution of planetary ages will be the same as the stellar ages: there will be planets of all ages, very young ones, very old ones. The very old ones will be smaller in mass in average as the remaining old stars are lower in mass (the higher-mass stars already reached their end of life and doing so likely lost their planet system in the end phase).